# how to whitelist with regex in graphite

Tags: regex, graphite

So I want to add something to my whitelist such that what ever begins with the prefix `a` and does not continue with `b` should be blocked.

**Example:**

```
a.b.blah -> Good
a.c.blah -> Bad, should be blocked
```

I am not sure as how to go about writing that particular regex. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the string `"a b"`, you can use `/a(?= *b)/`. Note that the space is in `(?= )` so that it's not returned as part of the match. That will see if it follows.

If you don't want it to follow, use `/a(?! *b)/`.